# make corrections vs make a registration

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Could anybody explain to me why we can say "make corrections" and "make a payment" but we can not say "make a registration", even though the grammatical rules are the same in the context (make + noun)

thank you in advance

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a "why"--a 'rule' you might generalize. There are things we *make* and other things we don't; *a registration* is just one of the things we don't *make* in Anglo English.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree that there's no rule. But instead of saying "make a registration," we say "register." What would you say instead of the other examples? "I read your paper and I corrected it" is not identical with "I made a correction," and "I received my Visa bill and I paid it" is not identical with "I made a payment" They differ in suggesting a complete or incomplete job of correcting or paying. So I think that we lack "make a registration" partly because the expression would be needless.

Answer (score -1):

The word "registration" is inherently different to the words "correction" and "payment"

The word "correction", used in the example you gave, means "a change that rectifies an error or inaccuracy". We say "make a correction" because the sentence "make a change that rectifies an error or inaccuracy" makes perfect sense.

The word "payment", used in the example you gave, means "an amount paid or payable". We can say "make a payment" because the sentence "make an amount [of money] paid" makes sense.

"Registration" however, can only mean "the action or process of registering or being registered". Saying "make the action or process of registering" is incredibly redundant considering we already have a single **verb** that represents that entire sentence. That verb is '**to register**'

Thus, we would not say "make a registration", but rather we would simply tell some to **register** (using 'to register' in its imperative form).

Comment: This is plain wrong. One of the meanings of _registration_ is **precisely** the thing that you make: see meaning 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/registration). The answer is actually "because that's the way English is". There is no rule. Nor is there an explanation in semantics, such as you have attempted to give.